# Elevator forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

We have an elevator with mass M with a person with mass m inside moving downwards with an acceleration $-a$.

The person is accelerated downwards by the force $-g\cdot m $ then by Newton's third law the ground will exert a force equal in magnitude $g\cdot m$. As the ground is now moving down with $-a $ we get another force on the ground, but why dont we take for that the mass of the accelerator M? Then the total force on the accelerator is $m\cdot g - M \cdot a $ and the total force on the person $-g\cdot m + a\cdot M $.

Why is that wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you have taken the acceleration of $Lift$ , but you're talking bout the acceleration of the Man

Comment: @Keshav Singh But the acceleration of the lift influcenes the acceleration of the Man?

Answer (score 2):

Since the person is moving with acceleration $-a$ (where we take upwards to be positive, and we assume $a <= g$) then the net force on them must be $-ma$. Since gravity exerts a force $-mg$ on the person, the force $F_1$ exerted on them by the lift must satisfy

$-ma = -mg + F_1 \\ \Rightarrow F_1 = m(g-a)$

By Newton's third law, the person exerts an equal and opposite force $-F_1$ on the lift. The lift is also accelerating with acceleration $-a$ so the net force on the lift must be $-Ma$. Taking into account the force of gravity on the lift which is $-Mg$, then there must be a further force $F_2$ exerted on the lift by its mechanism, which satisfies

$-Ma = -Mg -F_1 + F_2 \\ \Rightarrow F_2 = M(g-a) + F_1 = (M+m)(g-a)$

Of course, you could reach the same conclusion more directly by treating the person and the lift as a single object with mass $M+m$.

Answer (score -1):

There must be a Pseudo-Force Upward , (Opposite to the direction of $a$) . $$ma^*=mg-ma$$ Hence , $a^*=g-a$